# TextBlock, задать текстовое содержимое

Tags: c#, wpf

В проекте создал класс и пытаюсь внести изменения в содержимое TextBlock основного окна. В файле C# основного окна, где производится инициализация - все работает, содержимое меняется. А при попытке изменить содержимое из созданного мной класса - не работает. Почему?

```
class Async
    {
         public static async Task metod()
        {

            MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;


            int count = 0;
            long start, end;
            int i = 0;

            List<string> pairs = new List<string>() { "ADABTC", "ADXBTC", "ARPABTC" };

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();
            start = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            while (true)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();

                var tasks = pairs.Select(pair => client.GetAsync(API.BinanceApi._depth_string_request(pair)));



                var qw = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                Console.WriteLine(qw.Length);
                foreach (var c in qw)
                {

                    foreach (var b in API.BinanceApi.depth_JSON_parse(c.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString(), 100))
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(b.Key + " " + b.Value);

                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(BinanceApi.depth_JSON_parse(c.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString(),100));
                }
                count = count + qw.Length;
                end = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - start;
                if (end >= 60000)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    end = 0;
                    sw.Start();
                    start = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                }

                Console.WriteLine(end + " " + count);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
           mainWindow.textBlock.Text = "1234";


        }
    }
```

Вызываю этот метод в public Mainwindow, но изменений в Textblock не происходит.

Comment: Покажите как и откуда вызываете

Comment: Кстати, в таком варианте, как я указал в основном сообщении почему-то начало работать. Но, если я инициализирую mainWindow в начале функции, а изменить содержимое textblock пытаюсь в конце функции, то изменения не вносятся. Почему так?

Comment: Изменил основное сообщение с кодом, чтоб было понятнее.  
Сюда, в комментарии, не могу вставить код. Не знаю как отформатировать, чтоб он выглядел красиво.

Comment: Вызываю так:  Async.metod() в блоке public MainWindow после InitializeComponent();
Получается, что выполнение кода не заходит в блок while(true), а также не заходит ЗА него.

Comment: А в комментарии код вставлять и не надо. Вы правильно сделали, что исправили вопрос. Эта строка `foreach (var b in API.BinanceApi.depth_JSON_parse(c.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString(), 100))` ужасна. Во-первых вы объявляете методо асинхр., а делаете блокирующий вызов через Result. Во-вторых, делать матрешки из вызовов значить получить код, который тяжело отлаживать.

Comment: Я понимаю, что код некорректный, топорный, но я не программист ни разу - мне нужно чтоб код выполнял свой функционал и все. Я только знаю синтаксис и то не на 100%.   
По поводу вашего замечания: я еле-еле добился(с помощью форумов) того, чтоб запросы отправлялись параллельно, что ускорило работу примерно в 9 раз(по сравнению с синхронной отправкой запросов). Потом потратил некоторое время для получения результата из этих запросов.

Comment: Тяжело что-то подсказать, потому как тут вообще все нужно переписывать, от начала и до конца...

Comment: У вас там бесконечный цикл что ли? Как код, который расположен после бесконечного цикла может выполниться?

Comment: Понимаю. Но, почему если вставить строку mainWindow.textBlock.Text = "1234" до блока while, то изменения производятся, а, если в самом блоке или после него, то нет? Проблема в блоке while?    
В консольном приложении все работает как надо(весь метод).

Comment: После цикла, согласен, не может выполниться. А в нем почему не выполняется?

Comment: У вас цикл бесконечный. Он блокирует поток UI и потому ничего дальше не выводится. Внутри вы делаете блокирующие вызовы, что как бы тоже препятствует нормальной работе. Вам надо выводить результаты после того как вы их получите, т.е. вызываете метод, он должен вернуть результат, вы его потом показываете.

Comment: Внутри цикла не выполняется, потому что вы фризите поток UI бесконечным циклом. С UI нельзя так работать

Comment: Понял. Task.WhenAll(). 
  То есть, если этот код работает в консоли, то, чтобы он заработал в WPF его надо полностью переделывать? Нет такого варианта, чтобы поменять кусочек кода, а не весь?

Comment: UI-логика сама по себе сложна. Но первый шаг к переносимости — отделить бизнес логику в отдельные классы/проекты

Comment: Я вас правильно понял, что можно объединить два проекта и выполнять основную логику в консольном, а в визуальную часть только выводить необходимые данные?